# Legend labels of a NDVI image using R

Tags: r, legend, raster, landsat

I create an NDVI image from  Landsat 5 image, using the NDVI function that is shown below.  My problem is that  I can´t see the legend labels when I plot the NDVI file.

## 1. NDVI function (For Landsat 5 TM NIR = 4, red = 3)

```
NDVI <- function(img, i, k) {

    bi <- img[[i]]
    bk <- img[[k]]
    vi <- (bk - bi) / (bk + bi)
    return(vi)
}
ndvi <- NDVI(landsat_br, 3, 4)
```

## 2. Plot (The image range is between -1 and 1, the legend intervals were set to 0.5)

```
plot(ndvi, col = rev(terrain.colors(30)),legend=F,axes=F,  main = 'NDVI')

ndvi.range <- c(minValue(ndvi), maxValue(ndvi))
plot(ndvi, legend.only=T, col = rev(terrain.colors(30)),

    legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75,
    axis.args=list(at=seq(ndvi.range[1], ndvi.range[2], 0.5), 
    labels=seq(ndvi.range[1], ndvi.range[2], 0.5), 
    cex.axis=0.6),
    legend.args=list(text='NDVI', side=4, font=2, line=2.5, cex=0.8))
```

[As you see, I got the leyend without labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo5EK.png) 
[image]

Comment: Why not add the image into the post?

Comment: I added the image, it is linked to "As you see, I got the leyend without labels"

Comment: You need to include some example data so that this becomes reproducible. Either generate some data with code, or use a file that ships with R.